# OCIlib - Source and destination overlap in memcpy

Tags: c

I'm getting this error while checking the code in valgrind:

```
==19985== Source and destination overlap in memcpy(0x6d3c328, 0x6d3c328, 5)
==19985==    at 0x4A24F66: _intel_fast_memcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:894)
==19985==    by 0x551A6D7: kpufprow (in /opt/oracle/product/10.2/lib/libclntsh.so.10.1)
==19985==    by 0x5517FDE: kpufch0 (in /opt/oracle/product/10.2/lib/libclntsh.so.10.1)
==19985==    by 0x5516CB6: kpufch (in /opt/oracle/product/10.2/lib/libclntsh.so.10.1)
==19985==    by 0x540CA2F: OCIStmtFetch2 (in /opt/oracle/product/10.2/lib/libclntsh.so.10.1)
==19985==    by 0x4CDAF6E: OCI_FetchData (resultset.c:506)
==19985==    by 0x4CDB405: OCI_FetchNext (resultset.c:1117)
==19985==    by 0x402899: buildQotHash (c4.c:140)
==19985==    by 0x4036F6: main (c4.c:469)
```

I'm attaching the snippet. It is the part of mentioned function `buildQotHash`. I have marked line 140.

```
OCI_Connection* cn;
OCI_Statement* st;
OCI_Resultset* rs;
if (!OCI_Initialize(err_handler, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate( "db", "user",  "pass", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn);
char query[5000];
//here def of query
OCI_ExecuteStmt(st, query);
rs = OCI_GetResultset(st);
int i = 1;
int j = 0;
while (OCI_FetchNext(rs))<--- here is line 140
{}
```

I would prefer not to mess with `OCILIB`. Can I fix it outside from the lib?

Answer (score 0):

memcpy does not support overlapping memory regions. Use memmove if you cannot guarantee that the regions do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually asked a question, but I am presuming the question is 'why?'.

`memcpy` is being called by kpufprow. You would need the source of that to determine why.

Note many modern `memcpy` implementations (including, I believe, the modern gcc one, but don't bank on that) do allow overlapping src & dest, i.e. work like `memmove`. It may be the library knows this to be the case and thus you have a false positive.